# How to skip fsck check during the boot of ubuntu,since it uses SystemD

Tags: partitioning, systemd, fsck, chromebook

I would like to upgrade the kernel and I want to enable KVM on my old but still functional "Samsung Chromebook ARM model XE303C12 SNOW" because later I want to virtualize FreeBSD with qemu and kvm. I've started following this tutorial :

http://www.virtualopensystems.com/en/solutions/guides/kvm-on-chromebook/

As you can see,they used Ubuntu 13.04 as userland. No,I don't want to run such an old ubuntu version ! Actually my problem is that only 2 times over 10 tries my chromebook is able to boot correctly with the same setup. I've also completely erased the sd card with sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk1 status=progress bs=2M but very rarely it wants to boot. I don't understand where the error is. When I insert the sd card into the slot it beeps and it prepares itself to boot chrome OS from the internal memory,not Linux from the sd card.

The problem could be systemd or whatever does that,to check and fix disk errors because it does not support natively chrome os disk partitions flags. So it may break those flags after the first boot. So,I want to ask if there is a method that stops systemd or whatever to check and fix disk errors.

Please give a look at this site :

https://my.esecuredata.com/index.php?/knowledgebase/article/110/skip-or-permanently-bypass-fsck-check-on-linux

where it says :

Update: If your OS uses SystemD, the fsck check is unskippable during boot.

So,it seems that I can't skip the checking on a OS that uses systemd like ubuntu. Is this true ? thanks.

Comment: "Ubuntu 13.04 as userland. No,I don't want to run such an old ubuntu" so what version are you using?

Comment: I don't want to use ubuntu 13.04. I'm trying to use a newer userland. But before to attempt a new installation I need that someone reply to my question. Since the future ubuntu version installed on the chromebook,let's say 18.04, supports systemd,I can't use it if I don't find the method to deny to fsck to check the file system during the boot.

Comment: so what version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I've tried with ubuntu 14.04,but because the problem that I'm having I'm changing it with devuan beowulf. if it will not work I will come back to ubuntu 14.04. A more recent linux distro gives a lot of errors on the arm chromebook.

Comment: There are some modern operating systems like AnTiX that do not use systemd

Comment: Try `sudo systemctl disable systemd-fsckd.service` on a recent version of Ubuntu. Does that work?

Comment: If all you want to do is run KVM on a Chromebook you could try chromebrew